# Could not compile project in Intellij Idea 13 EAP/12.1.5 due to Lombok usages

Tags: intellij-idea, lombok

While trying Intellij Idea 13 EAP ( which I'm aware is not stable ) I could not compile/run a working project because of the following warning:

```
java: lombok.javac.apt.Processor could not be initialized. Lombok will not run during this compilation: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment cannot be cast to com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment
    at lombok.javac.apt.Processor.init(Processor.java:84)
    at lombok.core.AnnotationProcessor$JavacDescriptor.want(AnnotationProcessor.java:89)
    at lombok.core.AnnotationProcessor.init(AnnotationProcessor.java:143)
```

It's working very well with Intellij Idea 12, but I need to run on 13 because of an another issue fixed only in 13 ([IDEA-104616](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-104616))

This error comes up:

**com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment cannot be cast to com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment**

**Update:**

Created JetBrains issue: [IDEA-114130](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114130)

Comment: I would ask this on [IDEA issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).

Comment: I will do that... anyway, the issue can be in IDEA but in lombok as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an Intellij IDEA issue: [IDEA-114130](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114130)

> Fixed in build 132.474

Note: Reproducible in Intellij IDEA 12.1.5; avoid upgrade (in case of Lombok use) !

**UPDATE:
FIxed version is publicly released.**

Comment: It’s already fixed in #129.1344, download from http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-114130#comment=27-597719. Works for me.